# trying to filter choices with models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to filter the entries shown in the drop down select in the admin page.

```
class GroupDepartmentMembership(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey('department.Department', related_name="group_memberships")
    group = models.ForeignKey('group.Group', related_name="department_memberships", limit_choices_to={'pk__in': [m.group.pk for m in department.group_memberships.filter(lead__exact=True)]})
    lead = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

But then I am getting the following exception in the console, without any other stacktrace.

> Unhandled exception in thread started by <**main**.NewThreadStartup
>   instance at 0x28ff680>

Could you please help me spot the error? Thanks!

Comment: and do you not get the error if you remove the `limit_choices_to` option ?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I had to filter results in the ModelAdmin instead like @karthikr suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django admin you can limit the choices for foreign key using [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)